# Passing in a dataframe to a stateMachine from Lambda

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have two relatively large dataframes (less than 5MB), which I receive from my front-end as files via my API Gateway. I am able to receive the files and can print the dataframes in my receiver Lambda function. From my Lambda function, I am trying to invoke my state machine (which just cleans up the dataframes and does some processing). However, when passing my dataframe to my step function, I receive the following error:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (413) when calling the StartExecution operation: HTTP content length exceeded 1049600 bytes
```

My Receiver Lambda function:

```
dict = {}
dict['username'] = arr[0]
dict['region'] = arr[1]
dict['country'] = arr[2]
dict['grid'] = arr[3]
dict['physicalServers'] = arr[4] #this is one dataframe in json format
dict['servers'] = arr[5] #this is my second dataframe in json format

client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
response = client.start_execution(
    stateMachineArn='arn:aws:states:us-west-2:##:stateMachine:MyStateMachineTest',
    name='testStateMachine',
    input= json.dumps(dict)
)

print(response)
```

Is there something I can do to pass in my dataframes to my step function? The dataframes contain sensitive customer data which I would rather not store in my S3. I realize I can store the files into S3 (directly from my front-end via pre-signed URLs) and then read the files from my step function but this is one of my least preferred approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Passing them as direct input via `input= json.dumps(dict)` isn't going to work, as you are finding. You are running up against the size limit of the request. You need to save the dataframes to a file, somewhere the step functions can access it, and then just pass the file paths as input to the step function.

The way I would solve this is to write the data frames to files in the Lambda file system, with some random ID, perhaps the Lambda invocation ID, in the filename. Then have the Lambda function copy those files to an S3 bucket. Finally invoke the step function with the S3 paths as part of the input.

Over on the Step Functions side, have your state machine expect S3 paths for the `physicalServers` and `servers` input values, and use those paths to download the files from S3 during state machine execution.

Finally, I would configure an S3 lifecycle policy on the bucket, to remove any objects more than a few days old (or whatever time makes sense for your application) so that the bucket doesn't get large and run up your AWS bill.

---

An alternative to using S3 would be to use an EFS volume mount in both this Lambda function, and in the Lambda function or (or EC2 or ECS) that your step function is executing. With EFS your code could write and read from it just like a local file system, which would eliminate the steps of copying to/from S3, but you would have to add some code at the end of your step function to clean up the files after you are done since EFS won't do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for the input, so basically there is no other way to pass in large inputs to a step function unless I upload them to S3 first? 

Another approach I found is to directly tie my HTTP API to invoke my step function. That way I can just return `json.dumps(dict)` and the next step in my step function can receive it. This would basically mean that my receiverLambda function would be the first step in my step function

Comment: I would say there is no way to pass large inputs to a step function unless you save them **somewhere step functions can get to them** first. S3 isn't the only option, as I mentioned in my answer.